# Почему проект не запускается без sudo?

Tags: c#, linux, .net, ubuntu, .net-core

Имею Ubuntu и установленный dotnet core 2. Создал проект asp.net. Пытаюсь запустить его: `dotnet run`. На что мне ругается:

```
Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
```

Во первых мне не совсем понятно зачем ему вообще в дебаг-моде понадобился https? Во вторых я пытаюсь запустить `dotnet dev-certs https` и ловлю: `There was an error saving the HTTPS developer certificate to the current user personal certificate store.`.

При этом если запускать эту команду с `sudo` то сертификат генерируется и потом, опять же с `sudo dotnet run` - запускается все ок. Так что и было задумано? Почему я не могу без `sudo` проект запустить? Может прав на доступ какой-нибудь папке не хватает? Так скажите куда и каких прав раздать - я сделаю.

Answer (score 3):

Видимо для net-core приложения, которое хостится на kestrel указан https endpoint. Кестрел не сможет стартовать tls-эндпоинт из-за отсутствия сертификата (net core генерит self-signed сертификаты и закрывает ими https-endpoint, но они должны быть доверенными в системе). Выходов несколько:
1) Убрать https binding для приложения (либо в startup приложения, либо через env. Variable для kestrel 
ASPNETCORE_URLS)
2) Установить self-signed certificate в операционную систему

Подробнее можно прочесть тут https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visu

Comment: 1. Если вы об этой строке `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` то когда я ее убрал - ничего не изменилось.
2. По поводу установки сертификата - я же сказал что уже пробовал. Он установился, но без судо ничего не работает.

Кажется я нашел оптимальный выход - при создании проекта указать флаг `--no-https`.

Comment: HttpsRedirection не про то. Это принудиьелтные редиректы с http на https байндинги приложения. Нужно убрать UseHttps либо в коде либо в конфиге сервера(переменная  ASPNETCORE_URLS). Проблемы с sudo находятся на уровне OS. По всей видимости сертификат устанавливается не глобально а только для определенного юзера. Нужно проверить доверен ли сертификат от юзера от чьего имени стартует приложение

Comment: There was an error saving the HTTPS developer certificate to the current user personal certificate store - это значит что пользователю не хватает прав чтобы сохранить сертификат. Через sudo хватает видимо. Потом его еще нужно сделать доверенным. Для windows и macos net core cli умеет это делать сам с помощью команды. Для вашей OS смотрите как это сделать в доках